# Referencing a variable in a function c++

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to make sure that I understand what the use of the ampersand to reference a variable is. I know other similar questions have been asked but I would like to see if the code example I give uses it correctly.

example code:

```
 // function prototype
 GetBalance(float &balance);

int main()
{
    float balance;
    bool choice = true;

    if (choice == true)
         GetBalance(float &balance);
    else
        cout << "error" << endl;

    return 0;
}

GetBalance(float &balance)
{
    cout << "please enter the balance: " << endl;
    cin >> balance;

}
```

So in the main function the float variable is declared.

The function GetBalance references the variable declared in the main function. So that when the user enters a balance, the input is assigned to the balance variable.

Is this correct?

If not is what I want to do possible?

I would like to assign / pass the amount entered during the GetBalance functionto the variable "balance" declared in main().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (choice == true)
     GetBalance(float &balance);

This usage is wrong, it should be corrected to  s follows:

```
 if (choice == true)
         GetBalance(balance);
```

Except cosnstructors all functions in C++ should have return types. So function declaration and definition has to be corrected as follows in this case by adding return type `void`

```
void GetBalance(float &balance);
```

And on top of that you have to add required header files and namespaces in the program to get compile.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Variable are type sensitive in C++ so you have to change variable in function definition as follows:

```
void GetBalance(float &balance)
{
    cout << "please enter the balance: " << endl;
    cin >> balance;

}
```

After you make above changes this program will compile.
Then for your questions answers are follows:

> So that when the user enters a balance, the input is assigned to the
>   balance variable.
>
> Is this correct?
>   Ans : Yes

Comment: @kronis72 You aren't returning anything to the calling function. The way the reference works is it will change the value at the memory location of the passed in variable, so you don't need to return the value. You have to have a return specifier in your function signature, and in this case, it doesn't return anything, hence void is what you will need to use.

Comment: thanks alot!! I deleted the previous comment to re-word what I was trying to ask but you already answered before I could..... Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct of your usage in your

```
GetBalance(float &balance)
```

Method, however you need to call the method like this in your main():

```
GetBalance(balance);
```

As the type is already defined in the declaration.

Also, you may want to have some error checking with:

```
cin >> balance;
```

To check that the user is entering a float value.

**Edit** you need a return type on your function like

```
void GetBalance(float &balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you haven't quite got it right. What you would want is something like

```
float balance;

if(choice == true)
    GetBalance(balance)
```

This way balance is still in the scope of main, otherwise it will only be alive inside the call to the function. Now you will be able to use float anywhere in main.

Now that that is covered, we can discuss what is happening. You are declaring a float called balance. This reserves a place in memory. When you pass balance to the function `GetBalance(float &Balance)`, you will be referencing that location in memory, and modifying its value directly from that function.

Essentially the main problem was where you declared the variable, and the fact that you included an ampersand in the function call.